# Type annotation for a closure

Tags: rust

I have this code that I use in several places:

```rust
iterable.iter().map(|elem| f(elem, &mut acc))
```

where `f` is a function like `fn(T, &mut S) -> T`, taking an input, returning an output, and using the `acc: &mut S` to store some intermediate state (e.g. a `HashMap`). I wanted to refactor the code and create something like

```rust
struct MyIterator {
  iter: ???
}

impl MyIterator {
   fn new(iterable: Vec<T>, acc: &mut S) -> Self {
      Iterator {
         iter: iterable.iter().map(|elem| f(elem, &mut acc))
      }
   }
}
```

But I don't know what should be the type signature in `???`. Rust complains that closure cannot contain a captured variable.

## Example

I didn't want to overwhelm the question with unnecessary details, but I'll add an example as requested. I want `MyIterator` to follow the `Iterator` trait. Let's say that when iterating, at each `self.next()` step I want to post-process the results produced `self.iter.next()`. For example, `f` returns `Result<T, Error>` and I want an `Err` to stop the iterator while keeping the error message.

```rust
struct MyIterator {
    iter: ???
    err: Result<(), ()>
}

impl MyItertor {
    fn new(iterable: Vec<T>, acc: &mut S) -> Self {
        MyIterator {
            iter: iterable
               .iter()
               .map(|elem| f(elem, &mut ACC)),
            err: Ok(()),
        }
    }

    fn err(&self) -> Result<(), ()> {
       self.err
    }
}

impl Iterator for MyItertor {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match self.iter.next() {
            Ok(result) => result,
            Err(err) => {
                self.err = Err(err);
                None
            },
        }
    }
}
```

As for the types, it can be anything, making the code work for a trivial case like below will help me move along.

```rust
type T = i64;
type S = i64;

fn f(x: &T, acc: &mut S) -> Result<T, ()> {
    let y = x + *acc;
    *acc = y;
    if *acc > 100 {
        return Err(())
    }
    Ok(y)
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how you want to use your refactored code? It also has several things in it that won't compile: a `::` after `new` and two type parameters that are not defined anywhere. `f` is also not defined anywhere. It's also confusing to call your struct `Iterator` since that is the name of a fundamental trait in the standard library.

Comment: @Jimmy I fixed the issues. `f` is just some function that matches the given signature, for the sake of the question, I want to keep `S` also generic, it can be for example a HashMap where the values are read and written.

Comment: `T`, `S`, and `f` are still not defined in your implementation. Can you fix those and also add an example of how you want to use `MyIterator`?

Comment: @Jimmy done, though I'm not sure if those details would be helpful. The code example does not necessarily work, because I can't make it compile without the signature to move along, in the first place.

Comment: 1. Closures in Rust have [*anonymous types*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html), that is, **types that you cannot write**. This rules out writing the exact type. What you should use, instead, is a generic type `U`, and you could enforce it implementing `Fn(T, &mut S) -> T` (which is more general than the type `fn(T, &mut S) -> T`!), see [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html). 2. However, it is good practice (I don't remember where the reference for this is) to put type constraints in functions, not in types.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can make `MyIterator` generic over the type of the wrapped iterator:

```
struct MyIterator<I> {
    iter: I,
    err: Result<(), ()>,
}
```

Then, you can declare a free-standing `my_iter` function to serve as the constructor for a `MyIterator`. It returns a `MyIterator` parameterized over an anonymous iterator type via the `impl Trait` syntax:

```
fn my_iter<'a>(
    iterable: &'a Vec<T>,
    acc: &'a mut S,
) -> MyIterator<impl Iterator<Item = Result<T, ()>> + 'a> {
    MyIterator {
        iter: iterable.iter().map(|elem| f(elem, acc)),
        err: Ok(()),
    }
}

impl<I> MyIterator<I> {
    fn err(&self) -> Result<(), ()> {
        self.err
    }
}
```

Note that the associated type `Iterator::Item` in the return type must be equal to the return type of `f`. Also, `my_iter` is not placed in the `MyIterator` impl only because the function is not constrained by the type parameter `I` of the `impl`.

`Iterator` can then be implemented for `MyIterator` objects wrapping the type of iterator you need (i.e. the same type of iterator as created in `my_iter`):

```
impl<T, I: Iterator<Item=Result<T, ()>>> Iterator for MyIterator<I> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match self.iter.next() {
            Some(Ok(result)) => Some(result),
            Some(Err(err)) => {
                self.err = Err(err);
                None
            },
            None => None,
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=53ae9016adc0ff7c0db07f705d89abbf)